# CLASSIC ASP INSERT statement with parameters

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I have to mantain a ASP 3.0 website...

And I would like to protect sql statements.

The select statements I could protect with this code:

```
set cmd = Server.createObject("adodb.command")

cmd.commandText = "select from Foo where id=?"

set cmd.activeConnection = someConnection

set rs = cmd.execute(rows_affected, Array(42))
```

But I can't make it to work when I replace the select by update or insert statements.

Can anyone help me?

the code i am trying is:

```
sqlS1 = "INSERT into users (nome2) values (?)"

arParams = 1

set cmd = createobject("ADODB.Command") 

cmd.CommandText = sqlS1 

cmd.ActiveConnection = session("bdc")

cmd.Execute(,arParams,adExecuteNoRecords)
```

Comment: You cannot set a recordset (set rs) to an "action" query, just execute inserts and updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should run if you drop the parentheses:

```
cmd.Execute , arParams, adExecuteNoRecords
```

Or

```
cmd.Execute recs, arParams, adExecuteNoRecords
Response.write recs & " updated"
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! i was getting crazy....for the last four hours just because of the parentheses!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Remou's answer, note that you can use parentheses if you prefer (e.g. if you are used to C / Java type languages), by prefixing the sub invocation with the `Call` keyword:

`cmd.Execute recs, arParams, adExecuteNoRecords`

Or

`Call cmd.Execute(recs, arParams, adExecuteNoRecords)`